# How to configure that sent mail stays on the original folder of the reply and not in sent items

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Normal behabior is such that any mail sent, goes to sent-email.

How can I override this so that when I reply to a email which is filed in a folder, the reply gets automaticly filed in this folder as well and doesn't go to sent-items.

I'm using outlook 2010 with a exchange account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can override this in Outlook 2010.

Now under File > Options > Mail > Save messages section

I would suggest leaving the tick box for "Save copies of messages in Sent Items folder" so that works for the Inbox, and tick the option for "When replying to a message that is not in the Inbox, save the reply in the same folder"

Comment: +1 Right you are. That's the one I was thinking of.

Comment: funny, forgot about this question only to find again it with google. accepted!

Comment: Can you configure this in the Outlook Web App (OWA)?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure whether this feature is in Outlook 2010, but in Outlook 2007, you would disable this option: Tools > Options > E-mail options > Save copies of messages in Sent Items folder.

Comment: Yes, it is still there in 2010. Now under File > Options > Mail > Save messages.
I think there is a slightly better way to achieve exactly what the question asked, hence my additional answer